# Future Builder to make Sliver Lists

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to generate a dynamic list of slivers from a GET request. But I am having trouble, it seems the response data is null. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'boardSummary.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';


class HomepageBody extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {

    return HomepageBodyState();
  }
}

class HomepageBodyState extends State <HomepageBody> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Expanded(
      child: new Container(
        color: new Color(0xFF736AB7),
        child: new FutureBuilder <List<Post>>(
            future: fetchPost(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
              else
              return jobscroll(context, snapshot);
                  //: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }


        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<List<Post>>fetchPost() async {
final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1');

return compute(parsePosts, response.body);

}


List<Post> parsePosts(String responseBody){
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Post>((json)=>Post.fromJson(json)).toList();

}


class Post {

  final String userId;
  final String hashtag;
  final String price;
  final String description;

  Post({this.userId, this.hashtag, this.price, this.description});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      userId: json['userId'],
      hashtag: json['id'],
      price: json['title'],
      description: json['body'],
    );
  }

  }


 Widget jobscroll(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

  List data = snapshot.data;

   return CustomScrollView(
     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
     shrinkWrap: false,
     slivers: <Widget>[new SliverPadding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
       sliver: new SliverList(
         delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
               (context, index) => new BoardSummary(data[index]),
            childCount: data.length,
         ),
       ),
     ),
     ],
   );
 }
```

**BoardSummary** is a stateless widget class that just takes creates a "card" using the properties on each "Post". It takes in a object of type "Post."

The console spit out a lot of errors but this was the last one that seemed meaningful it also appeared in my emulator:

```
I/flutter (18882): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
```

**EDIT** Here's also the first few lines from my slack trace:

```
E/flutter (13964): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter (13964): #0      new Post.fromJson (file:///home/daniel/Desktop/testapp/lib/ui/homePageBody.dart:76:19)
E/flutter (13964): #1      parsePosts.<anonymous closure> (file:///home/daniel/Desktop/testapp/lib/ui/homePageBody.dart:60:40)
E/flutter (13964): #2      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:414:29)
E/flutter (13964): #3      ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:219:19)
E/flutter (13964): #4      parsePosts (file:///home/daniel/Desktop/testapp/lib/ui/homePageBody.dart:60:56)
E/flutter (13964): #5      _IsolateConfiguration.apply (package:flutter/src/foundation/isolates.dart:88:16)
E/flutter (13964): #6      _spawn.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/isolates.dart:96:30)
```

What should I do?

**Edit** casting this piece of code to string made it work, just have overflow to fix. If there is a better solution feel free to share!

```
  return Post(
      userId: json['userId'].toString(),
      hashtag: json['id'].toString(),
      price: json['title'].toString(),
      description: json['body'].toString(),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

`FutureBuilder` builds immediately even when the value is not yet available, because `build()` is sync and can't be delayed.

The `FutureBuilder` example shows how to check if the value is already available (`default: ...` and not `snapshot.hasError`):

```
new FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: _calculation, // a Future<String> or null
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none: return new Text('Press button to start');
      case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Awaiting result...');
      default:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        else
          return new Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: I still get the same error, not sure why. I'm getting JSON from Jsonplaceholder website.

Comment: You can't use `data.length` when `ConnectionState` is `none` or `waiting`.

Comment: Ahh I see if I take that off I just get a blank screen (with my background colour) no data is appearing which is odd. I added some more info from my slack trace, I think it's an issue with int being treated as a string, not sure.

Comment: As I said, it takes a while until the data arrives. Then the builder will be called again and `ConnectionState` will be changed. You can show a spinner or something like that while `ConnectionState` is `none` or `waiting`

Comment: Thanks I will add the spinner as well! I also was able to fix the issue by casting my object properties to strings. Not sure if this is a good solution but it works at the moment.

Comment: You mean casting for `userId: json['userId'] as String,` - yes, that's probably necessary.